# How to get application name and version relating to the foreground window in Python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, winapi, process

I want to register the application name and it's version relating to the foregroundwindow. I am able to get the application name as follows (in Python):

```
import win32gui
import win32process
import psutil

fgWindow = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
threadID, ProcessID = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(fgWindow)
procname = psutil.Process(ProcessID)
applicname = procname.name()
```

But I would like to know, for example, if it is OUTLOOK.EXE 2010 or OUTLOOK.EXE 2013. How could I retrieve this information from the system?

Comment: It depends on the app. In general what you attempt is impossible.

Comment: Once you have the full path to the process's executable file, you can use the Win32 `GetFileVersionInfo()` and `VerQueryValue()` functions to retrieve values from its version resource, such as its product name and version number. However, executables do not usually identify themselves they way you are looking for. Those names are usually for marketing purposes instead. So you will usually have to manually convert version numbers to more meaningful names on an app-by-app basis. [Outlook Version Numbers](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/outlook-version-numbers/)